# Opto isolator + triac vs. solid state relay for high AMP arduino project

Tags: arduino, relay, amperage

I building an arduino device to turn on/off a high current (~10A/120V) oven.  I was planning on using a solid state relay [like this](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/SSR40DA.pdf).

I keep seeing advice that talks about using an opto-isolator *AND* a triac for such things.  Am I misguided that a solid state relay with sufficient VOLT/AMP rating will work fine?

Comment: Just an update.  I've ended up using a triac + mechanical relay due to cost + heat (especially heat) reasons.  The solid state relay got up to 40C within 5 mins of use... which isn't acceptable.  Throwing a fan/heat sink adds more $$$ on top of the already $$$ SSR.  So... I'm going with a triac to control a 12V high amp mechanical relay instead.  It likely won't last as long as an SSR solution, but it's less than 1/4 the cost of the SSR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solid-state relay will work fine and I would suggest using it.

It integrates the triac (with galvanically isolated heat spreader), isolated triac driver, snubber and input current control circuit into one (hopefully) UL/CSA approved module.

You need to match the current/voltage ratings, and make sure you can keep the base of the module cool enough. At 10A you'll have about 10W to get rid of, which will require a fairly large heatsink or a fan. The same situation exists for a discrete triac but it's a little more difficult because you have to either isolate the triac or keep the heatsink isolated (dangerous, possibly) and spread the heat from a small TO-220 etc. package.

Comment: > hopefully UL/CSA approved module
LOL... yah, Made In China + ebay = probably not.
Could I also you to comment on why one should combine an opto-isolator and triac when that seems redundant.

Comment: @JayMarm The idea is to isolate the mains from your Arduino. The datasheet says they are UL but who knows? The isolation is not redundant- it keeps your Ardino, your computer (through the USB connection), and (not the least) **you** from incurring permanent damage. Best get someone who understands these hazards to check out your circuit before applying mains power.

Comment: thx for the quick response.  I hope you'll humor me a bit more.  Doesn't the opto-isolator alone protect/separate the hi/low volt sides??  Why is the triad also needed?  Isn't is opto-iso alone enough to switch the load on/off (if it's rated high enough) via the Arduino driving the low volt side?  Sorry if this a totally dumb question!

Comment: It won't be rated high enough. The opto cannot handle 10A. More like a few hundred mA. An opto good for high current is called an SSR. ;-)

Comment: Ahhh, ok. Thx for your assistance!!